# How set full url path for images in report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have installed Jasperserver at "hostname2" and "hostname1" is located at CMS.

I run a report on "hostname1" in which, html image links look like `/images/img_****` and are not displayed. They should have been, instead, like this: `http://"hostname2"/images/img_****`.

The main thing is that they have the correct link to the image... Has anyone faced with this kind of problem before?

Comment: You should use expressions like this: `<imageExpression><![CDATA["repo:/images/frog.png"]]></imageExpression>`

Comment: but what do with charts? report has no final name for the charts. how set normal url for charts and other generated resources?

Answer (score 0):

If your image is placed in the same directory where the .jasper(compiled jrxml files are present) then,

```
<imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["image_name.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
```

Comment: but what do with charts? report has no final name for the charts. how set normal url for charts and other generated resources?

Comment: If the charts which are generated are being generated by your application itself. Make sure they get generated and get saved with a particular name(if the number of generated resources is predefined). And you can mention the name in the expression.

Comment: what if the image_name.jpg is under a folder inside the compiled jrxml directory?